# What is the best and safest way to move files between HDDs in linux?

Tags: linux, rsync, mv

I have to move 5GB of data in certain folders (containing files smaller than 1MB) from an external HDD to another (both connected with USB 3.0). What is the best/safest way to make this transfer in Ubuntu?

My current options are

```
mv
rsync --remove-source-files
```

**NOTE:** I know that this question has been asked before, but I could not find a decisive answer, and you can imagine how important it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove the source till you're done. I typically use `rsync -a source destination` -   I let it run once, run it a second time to confirm all the files are moved over *and* consistent.

Safety is in *non destructive processes*.  Don't delete until you know its all there. Also, test with files you don't mind nuking. There's nothing worse than files being destroyed by a typo ;)

Comment: By default `rsync` only checks size and time to determine if a copy is needed, if you want to be really safe you should tell it to use checksums (`-c`).